# Fix the size of a JScrollPane of JPanels in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am a beginner in Java Swing and I am trying to put a multiple JPanels in a JScrollPanel. The matter is, the JSCrollPannel (named jp in the code) should not fill all the JFrame but it does even if I fix a size with setSize() and a maximal size with setMaximalSize(). What is the trouble? How can I make the JSCrollPane smaller than the JFrame?

```
    package GUI;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MultiPanels {
    private JScrollPane getContent() {
    Dimension d = new Dimension(300,200);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc= new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    panel.add(getPanel(d,  6, Color.red), gbc);
    panel.add(getPanel(d,  4, Color.green.darker()), gbc);
    panel.add(getPanel(d,  4, Color.orange), gbc);
    panel.add(getPanel(d, 12, Color.blue), gbc);
    panel.add(getEmptyPanel(d), gbc);

    return new JScrollPane(panel);
}

private JScrollPane getPanel(Dimension d, int rows, Color color) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.setBackground(color);
    GridBagConstraints gbc= new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,5);
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < rows; i++) {
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        panel.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(j++)), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(j++)), gbc);
    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(d);
    return scrollPane;
}

private JScrollPane getEmptyPanel(Dimension d) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0,0,Color.red,
                                                 0,h,Color.cyan);
            ((Graphics2D)g).setPaint(gp);
            g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
        }
    };

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(d);
    return scrollPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    JScrollPane jp =  new MultiPanels().getContent();
    jp.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    jp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));


    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(jp);


    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time things don't size or arrange correctly, you have to look into Layouts.

Generally, spend more time on:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

To be specific, the default layout of a `JPanel` and `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` which is a very simple layout manager indeed. When you add to a component managed by `BorderLayout` without saying where, it is automatically added to the center and fills to use all available space:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border

It is possible to use "none" (Absolute Positioning) as the layout, but this is almost always a bad idea and you want to think about what you really want to do with the rest of the space in the JFrame: perhaps by letting new child components, with their own size demands, take up some of the space that the main panel is now swallowing up.